# Is there a way to change a post's thumbnail image(s)?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, social-sharing, sharing

I just recently finished the first version of a blog (here: http://northernconservative.com/ ), but whenever I share a post on social media, the thumbnail image is the atrocious scaled up version of one of the social media icon's I have on the footer.

I would really like that the thumbnail image be the logo which is on top of the site. According to my research, I could make it my Blavatar, however I ended up discovering that I could only use that if the host was also Wordpress, which it isn't.

Regardless, what could I do (if anything) to use better images to appear on my thumbnails whenever sharing links? I have also attempted to add an image on the post, but that doesn't come as an option for the thumbnail image either.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Another note on your site: You can change the permalinks to the pages so the URL does not look like: /blog-2/ but /blog/ you probably have some old 'blog' and 'about us' pages in the trash, empty the trash and you can use the 'blog' and 'about-us' again :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I had not noticed I left those behind in the trash. I fixed that and will make sure to keep an eye out for it for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook scrapes your pages for images to go along with the post you share. When it finds an image on the page it will use that.

To specify which image exactly you have to use [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) tags in the `head` part of you html page. The `og:image` tag in particular:

```
<meta property="og:image"
content="http://graphics.myfavnews.com/images/logo-100x100.jpg" />
```

Here is a [list of plugins that insert the Open Graph tags](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/10/5-free-plugins-adding-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-wordpress/) for you. 
If you like to put the [Open Graph-tag code in functions.php](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-facebook-open-graph-tags-to-wordpress) yourself, check this article.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I've added the recommend Open Graph plugins and set the images as I would like them to be. It all seems to work on the Open Graph Tester of the last article you sent me. Unfortunately not only does it still not work, but I cannot find the og tags in any of the files. Am I missing something?
I also tried to add the code manually as shown in the second article you sent me too, still nothing... Am I missing something?

This is getting quite frustrating :(

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I have used the Open Graph tester at the end of the article you sent me, and none of the images I've actually defined are being the ones found on it. Instead, it is the image featured in the blog post or, on the front page, the background image used on it. Is that supposed to be right?

Comment: One more thing, I just realized whenever I edit the blog post, I get a bunch of notifications from the NGFB plugin talking about conflicts detected. However they don't give me anything direction on what to do about it. Could this be one of the reasons things aren't working?

Comment: Ignore all my previous comments. I'm not sure what I did, but after plenty of messing around it now works as I wanted it to.
Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: No sweat :) I am glad I could help! Good luck with your project